# How to get item weight from walmart open API

Tags: c#

1) I am using Walmart open-API to find the product. But my requirement is to get the item weight, that is not available on the response of the product. So anyone help me how to get item / product weight from the API?

2) We are getting category list by using the URL below 2) but how to consume the category list? please help me on this.

We tried walmart open API with below URLs. Getting item decription but not finding the item weight in response.

### Finding Item details:-

1)
http://api.walmartlabs.com/v1/items/55505580?format=json&apiKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

### Listing the item categories:-

2)
http://api.walmartlabs.com/v1/taxonomy?apiKey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&format=json

Comment: can you provide a link to the documentation of the API? Mostly we are not experts in the specifics of some particular API on this site.

Comment: See walmart site : https://developer.walmartlabs.com/docs.  The sample response contains weight so the options in the request on link give weight.  The sample response is json but webpage says xml is also available.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see in the API Docs, weight is not a value that can be returned directly in the JSON, but appears to be included in the description text. Your best bet is to search for it there, although the consistency of the result may be a concern as its not an attribute, just a description. I'm not sure how reliable WalMart will be in providing weights in the descriptions for all their products.

The [example](https://developer.walmartlabs.com/docs) here shows the weight in the description as `Weight: 3.95 oz`.

You could do something like this with the deserialized JSON response:

```cs
Regex regex = new Regex(@"Weight:.*oz")
Match match = regex.Match(response.longDescription); // Response would be the JSON response as an object. longDescription contains the description
if(match.Success)
{
    weight = match.Value;
}
```

But this of course relies on the weight always being in ounces, you may need to adjust the Regex to your needs.

Comment: But i did't found any weight attribute in response. Is walmat openAPI is enough to get the item weight? Or am i using the correct API?

Comment: Walmart has no attribute in its JSON response for weight specifically. As I explained in my answer, it appears to be included in the `longDescription` attribute. This isn't desirable as it may or may not be included on every product(I can't confirm this). If the API isn't consistent, you may need to look for an alternative API